# jQuery setting & getting localstorage data for dropdowns & input's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a simple form page have some localstorage functionality to restore settings/input after the page has been closed/reloaded.

I've attempted to make a start but I am still learning so there are mistakes and I can't get it to work.

- If a change is made to the name `input` field it should update the localstorage with the new name.
- If a change is made to any of the dropdown (selector? option?) fields it should update the localstorage with the new value.
- On page load it should **automatically restore** all of the values.
- The "Clear" button should **ONLY** reset the dropdown (selector? option?) fields to blank, it should **NOT** reset the name field.

#### Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5gam3b6f/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($("select"), function (index, value)) {
        localStorage.getItem($(this).attr(“id”));
    };
});

$("select").on("change", function () {
    localStorage.setItem($(this).attr(“id”), $(this));
});
```

I haven't managed to start on the name input field or the clear function yet because I can't even get the first one to work.

I would rather not use external libraries as this is as complicated as it will get, nothing else needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will work for you:

[Here is a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/7v7gvwcc/2/)

**jQuery**

```
$('.useLocalSelect').change(function () {
    var key = $(this).attr('id');
    var value = $(this).val();
    localStorage.setItem(key, value)
});

// use a timer for text fields and the like so that localsotrage is set 2 seconds after the user stops typing instead of after each keystroke
var t = '';
$('.useLocalInput').keyup(function () {
    clearTimeout(t);
    var key = $(this).attr('id');
    var value = $(this).val();
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value)
    }, 2000);
});

$('.useLocal').each(function () {
    var key = $(this).attr('id');
    if (localStorage.getItem(key)) {
        $(this).val(localStorage.getItem(key));
    }
});

$('.clearLocalSelect').click(function () {
    $('.useLocalSelect').each(function () {
        $(this).val('');
        var key = $(this).attr('id');
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 14px Tahoma;">Input &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input class="useLocal useLocalInput" id="testInput" size="40" type="text" name="website" value="" required/>
</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 14px Tahoma;">Select</label>
<select class="useLocal useLocalSelect" id="testSelect" name="start_date">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">Noember</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
    <input type="button" class="clearLocalSelect" value="Clear Selects"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I can definitely get my head around that to fit it for my needs! The only thing I dont understand/get is what the css .useLocal is for because I can't get any red to show anywhere...

Comment: My bad, ignore that, I was testing something and forgot to remove it : )

Comment: Phew, I was scratching my head trying to figure it out :P Thank you for your help, this will help me in the long run massively as I am trying to get the hang of localstorage.

Comment: What's the negative to having the name field update the local storage instantly?

Comment: Honestly, you could let it work instantly. I don't think there's a typist fast enough to cause any real problems. IMHO, it's just good practice to not act on text fields until the user is finished typing.  Especially if you start to do other things later like filtering a table or something where the operation performed would have more overhead. : )